# Silverlight changes the io.Stream to byte[]

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0

I have created a WCF service for uploading images , which accepts `System.IO.Stream` as input parameter and am using streaming. When I added the service reference in Silverlight project then it automatically changed the parameter of my WCF method from `System.IO.Stream` to `byte[]`. Can anyone suggest if there is a way around this so that I can get `System.IO.Stream` type rather than `byte[]`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want this? Are you trying to get an upload progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify that you're not hitting one of the reader quotas in the service? You can try increasing all of them to see if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight does not support transfer mode streamed:  http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/119340.aspx

So I think that you are stuck with getting a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set the `transferMode` property of your `basicHttpBinding` to the correct value, as described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx). And then add the service reference to your Silverlight application again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already have that property set to "Streamed". When I add this service reference in Windows project it shows IO.Stream but when I add this as service reference in silverlight project it comes out as byte[]

Comment: As Shiraz correctly points out and as I have just learned, Silverlight only supports buffered transfer mode. You could try to implement a solution that uploads an image piece by piece.

Comment: rwwilden - Silverlight supports Streamed mode as well, what Shiraz meant was System.Io.Streaming is not supported by silverlight when used as parameter in wcf service

Comment: But when I attempt to programmatically configure a BasicHttpBinding inside a Silverlight client, the property TransferMode does not even exist on the BasicHttpBinding. So the only possible way is via sockets, I suppose?

Comment: On Silverlight client we cannot configure transfer mode it can be configured only on WCF service. there are many limitation in silverlight

Answer (score 0):

Even I was struggling with the same issue. At last I got a solution by myself. All you can do is:

1. declare the accepting parameter as string array in the  WCF Service.
2. convert the byte array into string array at client place.
3. After Sending the converted byte array as string array again convert back it into byte array.

eg. at the WCF side:

```
[DataContract]
Class FileInfo  
{
 [DataMember] 
 string filename;
 [DataMember]
 string[] StrArr;
}
```

the receiving function:

```
public void uploadFile(FileInfo fi)
{
 int len=fi.StrArr.len;
 byte[] myFileByte=new byte[len];

 for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
  myFileByte[i]=Convert.ToByte(fi.StrArr[i]);
 }
 //your uploaded File buffer is ready as myFileByte
 //proceeding operations are most welcome here......
.........
}
```

At Client Side:

```
public void UploadMyFile()
{
 //Take the InputStream from the selected File as iStream;
 int len=(int)iStream.length;
 byte[] buffer=new byte[len];
 string[] MyStrArr=new string[len];

 for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
  MyStrArr[i]=Convert.ToString(buffer[i]);
 } 
  //Here your string array is ready to send to the WCF Service....
  //I m confident this code will work perfectly with some file limitation consideartions. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/07/08/using-transfermode-streamedresponse-to-download-files-in-silverlight-4.aspx